# github can't load resources error

Tags: github

I uploaded a site on github but it doesn't show images or .js files.
In console there is this mistake *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*
 [This is the link](http://kiraburova.github.io/ModernLook/)
I have another site in the same repository and everything works fine there.
[Repository](https://github.com/KiraBurova/KiraBurova.github.io)

I tried it in both Chrome and Opera

Comment: It clearly says file not found. Are you sure all the files are in your FTP folder ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was simply in wrong paths to my files.